# ruby loop next case example

Tags: ruby

I am trying to loop through multiple statements, but want to go through each one once, example:

```
while count < 5 do
  count+= (not sure if this how ruby increments counts)
  puts "In condition one"
  next if count > 1
  puts "In condition two"
  next if count > 1
  #..
end
```

**Update 1:**

Thanks for the reply, what I'm trying to do is loop through an array and have each element of the array be applied to 10 different conditions. For example: array[has 100 elements] element 1 gets condition 1, element 2 goes on to condition 2, and so on. Since there are 10 conditions, the 11th element in the array would get condition 1 again, and so on (condition 1 condition 2 condition 3 ...)

**Update 2:**

Thanks again for taking the time to reply. I apologize that I'm not being very clear. The array contains emails. I have 10 email servers and want to send the 200 emails I have in my array through each server (only 1 email per server). I hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're are asking for. Why loop at all?

Comment: I have an array that I want to loop through, but each element in the array needs to go through a different condition each time and then restart at the first condition.

Comment: You should edit your question to add more details about what you are actually trying to do. It sounds like you may be going about it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, you want to send a large number of emails through a small number of servers while balancing the load.  Try creating a class to manage the servers (here's the basic idea)

```
class ServerFarm
    def initialize
        @servers = []
    end

    attr_accessor :servers

    def add_server(server)
        @servers << server
    end

    def remove_server(x)
        if x.is_a?(Numeric) then
            @servers.delete_at(x)
        elsif x.is_a?(Server)
            @servers.delete(x)
        end
    end

    def server_available?
        @servers.each {|s| return true if s.available? }
        false
    end

    def dispatch_message(email)
        @servers.each_with_index {|s, i|
            next unless s.available?
            s.dispatch(email)
            return i
        }
        nil
    end
end
```

Now, all you will have to do is call `ServerFarm.dispatch_message` for an email and it will be sent using one of the available servers.  This class assumes that you have a class named `Server` that holds the info for your individual servers, etc etc.

Comment: My answer was in response to the OP's updates, which he posted as comments to Adrian's answer instead of updating the question.  I'll edit the question and copy them there to prevent confusion.

Comment: How does this solution balance the load?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? I can't tell what you are trying to do.

```
5.times do |count|
  puts 'In condition ' + %w(one two three four five)[count]
end
```

The `5.times do |count|` will excecute the block five times with `count` starting at zero and incrementing each time. `%w(one two three four five)` is the same as `["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]`.

If you want to do five different things consecutively, you do not need a loop. Just put the statements in a row:

```
# do thing 1
# do thing 2
# do thing 3
# ...
```

**Edit**:

"I have an array that I want to loop through, but each element in the array needs to go through a different condition each time and then restart at the first condition."

To loop through an array endlessly, testing each element against conditions:

```
arr = ['sdfhaq', 'aieei', 'xzhzdwz']

loop do
  arr.each do |x|
    case x
    when /..h/
      puts 'There was a \'h\' at the third character.'
    when /.{6}/
      puts 'There were at least six characters.'
    else
      puts 'None of the above.'
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit 2**:

"Thanks for the reply, what I'm trying to do is loop through an array and have each element of the array be applied to 10 different conditions, example: array[has 100 elements] element 1 gets condition 1 element 2 goes on to condition 2 and so on, since there are 10 conditions the 11th element in the array would get condition 1 again and so on. condition 1 condition 2 condition"

You will need to use the `%` method on numbers.

```
arr = Array.new(130) # an array of 130 nil elements.
num_conditions = 10

arr.each_with_index do |x, i|
  condition = (i + 1) % num_conditions
  puts "Condition number = #{condition}"
end
```

More information: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001059

**Edit three**:

```
def send_an_email(email, server)
  puts "Sending an email with the text #{email.inspect} to #{server}."
end

email_servers = ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
emails = ['How are you doing?', 'When are you coming over?', 'Check out this link!']

emails.each_with_index do |email, i|
  send_an_email email, email_servers[i % email_servers.length]
end
```

You can modify `email_servers` and `emails` and have it still work, even if the lengths are changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I'm trying to do is loop through an array and have each element of the array be applied to 10 different conditions, example:

array[has 100 elements]

element 1 gets condition 1 element 2 goes on to condition 2 and so on, since there are 10 conditions the 11th element in the array would get condition 1 again and so on.

condition 1
condition 2
condition 3

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to reply. I apologize that I'm not being very clear. The array contains emails, I have 10 email servers and want to send the 200 emails I have in my array through each server (only 1 email per server). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: If that last edit helped at all, could you click the checkmark icon near the top of my answer? I will still be happy to help. Thanks. :)

Comment: I appreciate your help! That should do the trick. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
array = (1..100).to_a
conditions = (1..10).to_a

array.each_with_index do |elem, i|
  puts "element %d, using condition %d" % [elem, conditions[i % conditions.length]]
end
```

produces

```
element 1, using condition 1
element 2, using condition 2
element 3, using condition 3
element 4, using condition 4
element 5, using condition 5
element 6, using condition 6
element 7, using condition 7
element 8, using condition 8
element 9, using condition 9
element 10, using condition 10
element 11, using condition 1
element 12, using condition 2

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_slice(10) do |emails|
    servers.zip(emails) { |server,email| server<<email }
end
```

(Ruby 1.9.2)